# How to remove an array of words from a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function that can remove words from a string. It is :

```
  var removeFromString = function(oldStr, fullStr) { 
    return fullStr.split(oldStr).join(''); 
  };
```

I use it like this :

```
 console.log( removeFromString("Hello", "Hello World") ); // World
 console.log( removeFromString("Hello", "Hello-World") ); // -World
```

But the main problem :

```
 var str = "Remove one, two, not three and four";
```

Here we have to remove "one", "two" & "four". This can be done by :

```
var a = removeFromString("one, two,", str); // Remove not three and four
var b = removeFromString("and four", a); // Remove not three
console.log(b); // Remove not three
```

In the above example, I had to use the function twice. I want it to be something like this :

```
 var c = removeFromString(["one, two," , "and four"], str); // Remove not three
 console.log(c); // Remove not three
```

Yes, I actually want to upgrade the removeFromString function ! How can I do that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `join` and build regex dynamically from the array and replace the matching values

```js
function removeFromString(arr,str){
  let regex = new RegExp("\\b"+arr.join('|')+"\\b","gi")
  return str.replace(regex, '')
}

console.log(removeFromString(["one, two," , "and four"],"Remove one, two, not three and four" ));
console.log(removeFromString(["one" , "and four"],"Remove one, two, not three and four" ));
console.log(removeFromString(["Hello"], "Hello World") )
```

---

To cover cases where your word to match can have meta-characters you can expand the above example in this way

```js
function escape(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

function removeFromString(arr, str) {
  let escapedArr = arr.map(v=> escape(v))
  let regex = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)"+escapedArr.join('|') + "(?!\\S)", "gi")
  return str.replace(regex, '')
}

console.log(removeFromString(["one, two,", "and four"], "Remove one, two, not three and four"));
console.log(removeFromString(["one", "and four"], "Remove one, two, not three and four"));
console.log(removeFromString(["Hello"], "Hello World"))
console.log(removeFromString(["He*llo"], "He*llo World"))
console.log(removeFromString(["Hello*"], "Hello* World"))
```

Comment: I would just suggest sanitizing the strings to avoid building an invalid regexp, and making it able to search for special chars such as `.`, `*`, etc... More info: [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Escaping)

Answer (score 4):

Another approach using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
function removeFromString(words, str) {
  return words.reduce((result, word) => result.replace(word, ''), str)
}

const str = "Remove one, two, not three and four"
const result  = removeFromString(["one, two, " , "and four"], str)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Great use of `Array.prototype.reduce`. Just one remark: it would be better to use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`, if you want to replace all occurences of **word**.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
function removeFromString(arr, str){
    arr.forEach(w => str = str.replace(w, ''));
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Hi Mo, please add a description to your answer as to how this solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
wordArray.forEach(word => {
    sentence = sentence.replace(word, '');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
function newRemoveFromString(stringArray,string){

    for(var i=0;i<stringArray.length;i++){

        string=removeFromString(stringArray[i],string);

    }
    return string;
}
```

It loops through the words in the Array and removes them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
function replaceStr(myString,list)
  {
    $.each(list,function(i,item){
    myString=myString.replace('Hello', item);
    });   
  }
  
  /*Now use this fucntion like this */
replaceStr(yourstring,arrayOfWords);
or replaceStr(yourString,{"word1","word2"});
```