# Remove specific words from a string in an efficient way

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to strip out a couple of matching words from an array of string. Below is the array containing the string

```
let string = ["select from table order by asc limit 10 no binding"]
```

I am trying to get rid of any that has order by and limit and its value and preserving the remaining. I have tried the following but none of them are elegant/efficient.

```
let splitString = string.split(' ');
let str1 = 'limit';
let str2 = 'order';
let str3 = 'by';
let str4 = 'asc';
let str5 = '10';

splitString = splitString.filter(x => x !== str1);
splitString = splitString.filter(x => x !== str2);
splitString = splitString.filter(x => x !== str3);
splitString = splitString.filter(x => x !== str4);
splitString = splitString.filter(x => x !== str5);
```

Is there a proper way of getting rid of those words from the string? TIA

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an array of words from a string in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376549/how-to-remove-an-array-of-words-from-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array or Set of the strings you want to remove, then filter by whether the word being iterated over is in the Set.

```js
const input = ["select from table order by asc limit 10 no binding"]
const wordsToExclude = new Set(['limit', 'order', 'by', 'asc', '10']);
const words = input[0].split(' ').filter(word => !wordsToExclude.has(word));
console.log(words);
```

If you don't actually want to remove all of those words, but only such a *sequence*, use a regular expression to match `limit` until you come across numbers.

```js
const input = ["select from table order by asc limit 10 no binding"];
const result = input[0].replace(/order\b.*?\d+ /, '');
console.log(result);
```

If additional numbers can come in between the sequence, match `limit \d+` at the end, rather than just `\d+`

```js
const input = ["select from table order by 1 asc limit 33 no binding"];
const result = input[0].replace(/order\b.*?limit \d+ /, '');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: this would actually be risky as there could be other occurences of the word by and the number 10. Is there any way to remove the substring from order to the number exceeding the limit keyword?

Comment: That was not specified in your question. Will the input always contain `order... limit <someNumber>`?

Comment: yes it will always contain that

Comment: sorry I should have been more specific, I thought everything that falls in between `order .... limit <someNumber>` would be replaced. So the string can look this as well `order by 1 asc limit <someNumber>` and the updated answer of yours does not seem to work

Comment: Reopening this, this would not work if the string has substrings in them like 'select from "tablenames", "some random text" order by 1 asc limit 10 no binding'. I take the blame again, sorry for not being specific

Comment: That results in `select from "tablenames", "some random text" no binding`, what were you hoping for instead?

Comment: It does not work if there are multiline comments

Comment: `const input = [`select
"tablename",
"some random text",
 group by 1, 2 order by 3 desc limit 10000`];
const result = input[0].replace(/order\b.*?limit \d+ /, '');
console.log(result);`

Comment: To match newlines with `.` in a regular expression, add the `s` flag. eg `/./s` will match newline characters. Add that flag and they'll be matched.

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` and `includes`

```js
const [string] = ["select from table order by asc limit 10 no binding"];
const exclude = ["limit", "order", "by", "asc", "10"];

const res = string.split(" ").filter(wd => !exclude.includes(wd));

console.log(res)
```

Alternatively using `replaceAll`

```js
const [string] = ["select from table order by asc limit 10 no binding"];
const exclude = ['limit', 'order', 'by', 'asc', '10'];

const res = exclude.reduce((str, word) => 
  str.replaceAll(word, ''), string).replaceAll(/\s+/g, ' ');
  
console.log(res)
```